# zend framework: zend form create multiply radio buttons

Tags: zend-framework, radio-button, zend-form

I need to create about 10 radios for my star rating. At the end i need this html code:

```
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled" />
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled" />
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled" />
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled" />
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled" />
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled" />
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled"  checked="checked" />
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled" />
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled" />
 <input name="star2clinic" type="radio" class="star {split:2}" disabled="disabled" />
```

but im only know how to create one radio element (`$input_new = $this->createElement('radio','Stars' ,array(
                            'label' => 'Stars',
                            'Options' => array('class'=>'star {split:2}')));`) and create handly all 10 element will looks crazy :)
Give some reciepe please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `addMultiOptions`.

Comment: im try use it but nothing at result. Can you write some example?

Answer (score 1):

I think there may be a problem: Zend_Form_Element_Radio will wrap each radio with `<label for="elementName-1">...</label><br>`. This doesn't work with jquery star rating.

You can do a quick workaround:

`$('.row_stars input:radio').unwrap();
$('.row_stars br').remove();`